# Prove $1-2\int_{0}^{\infty}{\tan^{-1}(x)\over e^{x\pi}-1}dx=\ln(2)$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, closed-form

I want to prove the following:

> $$J=1-2\int_{0}^{\infty}{\tan^{-1}(x)\over e^{x\pi}-1}dx=\color{red}{\ln(2)}.$$

My attempt: we know that $$\tan^{-1}(x)=x-{x^3\over 3}+{x^5\over 5}-\cdots$$

Plugging in, we obtain, $$J=1-2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2n-1}\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{2n-1}\over e^{x\pi}-1}dx$$

Recall that, $${\pi^{2s}\over \Gamma(2s)}\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{2s-1}\over e^{x\pi}-1}dx=\zeta(2s)$$

Finally, we have,$$J=1-2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2n-1}{\Gamma(2n)\zeta(2n)\over \pi^{2n}}$$

I need help on evaluating the sum $J$. Some help please?

Comment: for now, we can simplify the sum without $\Gamma$ nor $\zeta$, is it enough?

Comment: Can you explain bro. What are you saying?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I waited a lifetime for this moment!

> It is enough to use [Binet's second $\log\Gamma$ formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinetsLogGammaFormulas.html) with $z=\color{red}{\frac{1}{2}}$.

Notice that you cannot simply plug in the Taylor series for the arctangent function, since the radius of convergence of its power series at $x=0$ is finite (it is $1$), so that way you get a divergent series. But Binet's second $\log\Gamma$ formula is a not so difficult consequence of Frullani's theorem or the Abel-Plana formula, since $\arctan(x)=\text{Im}\log(1+ix)$.

Comment: +1. I was thinking in Abel-Plana when your fine answer arrived. It's the straightforward one.

Comment: Why is $\arctan x = \operatorname{Im} \log(1+ix)$?

Comment: @GFauxPas: because if $x\geq 0$ $$1+ix = \sqrt{x^2+1} e^{i\arctan x}$$ by De Moivre's formula.

Answer (score 3):

We have $$I=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\arctan\left(x\right)}{e^{\pi x}-1}dx=\sum_{k\geq1}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-k\pi x}\arctan(x)dx
 $$ $$=\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{1}{k}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-k\pi x}}{1+x^{2}}dx\tag{1}
 $$ and this is the Laplace transform of $\frac{1}{1+x^{2}}$ at $s=\pi k$. This integral can be expressed in terms of the [Sine integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SineIntegral.html) function and [Cosine integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CosineIntegral.html) function (it follows from the Laplace transform of the sine function), but in our case the integral is $$I=\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}}{k}\left(\frac{\textrm{Si}\left(k\pi\right)}{\pi}-\frac{1}{2}\right)\tag{2}
 $$ $$=\frac{\log\left(2\right)}{2}-\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}}{k}\textrm{Si}\left(k\pi\right)
 $$and now we can observe from the Taylor series of the $\textrm{Si}\left(k\pi\right)
 $ function that $$\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}}{k}\textrm{Si}\left(k\pi\right)=\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}}{k}\sum_{m\geq1}\left(-1\right)^{m}\frac{\left(k\pi\right)^{2m-1}}{\left(2m-1\right)\left(2m-1\right)!}
 $$ $$=\sum_{m\geq1}\left(-1\right)^{m}\frac{\pi^{2m-1}}{\left(2m-1\right)\left(2m-1\right)!}\zeta\left(-2m+2\right)
 $$ $$=\zeta\left(0\right)\pi=-\frac{\pi}{2}
 $$ since $\zeta\left(-2m\right)=0,\,\forall m\geq1$ and this conclude the proof.

**Note.** A way for proving $(2)$ from $(1)$ is the following: 
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-sx}}{1+x^2}dx
&=\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty e^{-sx}e^{-xy}\sin(y)dydx\\
&=\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(y)}{s+y}dy\\
&=\int_s^\infty\frac{\sin(y)\cos(s)-\cos(y)\sin(s)}{y}dy\\
&=\textrm{Ci}(s)\sin(s)+\frac{\pi\cos(s)}{2}-\textrm{Si}(s)\cos(s).
\end{align}
$$